# ¿Cómo ejecuto el index.php de manera automática al iniciar un proyecto en Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-6

Estoy creando un proyecto utilizando Lravel 6 (es un proyecto de práctica para un curso que sigo, por eso utilizo una versión antigua), en conjunto con Laragon.

Laragon me permite tener URL's mas amigables para el desarrollo pero, al ingresar a mi proyecto a través del navegador, en vez de dirigirse a la carpeta public/index.php de forma automática, me arroja el listado de carpetas dentro del proyecto.

Intenté configurando el archivo de .htaccess para intentar que cada vez que ponga la url, el primer archivo que ejecute sea el index.php pero, no lo logré así que lo volví a dejar como estaba por defecto.

¿Alguien sabría cómo solucionar esto?

Dejo un screen de como me aparece y la configuración del archivo .htaccess, muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: Estos son los archivos iniciales del framework]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usaste en `.htaccess` y la versión de Apache y módulos instalados. De hecho, en la imagen no aparece ese archivo.

Comment: Debes rutear a `/public` si no me equivoco.

Comment: Saludos @JonatanLavado. Exacto, el problema es que no sé cómo hacerlo y si no me equivoco, creo que tendría que ser desde el archivo de .htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Stackoverflow Inglés ya se abordó esta pregunta, te dejo aquí la respuesta.

Lo que recomiendan es que en tu htaccess modifiques el rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Link a la pregunta original [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040502/how-do-you-redirect-all-request-to-public-folder-in-laravel-5).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo implementé tal cual al mismo nivel que mi carpeta public en un nuevo archivo .htaccess y me funcionó. Excelente aporte.